# Ordenar un array en javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero ordenar un array con distintos elementos por fecha de mas próximo (a partir de hoy) a mas lejano en tiempo y no logro entender como hacerlo.

Este sería mi array (de ejemplo) que quiero ordenar y mi profesor pidió que usaramos `sort()`:

```javascript
let solicitudesCarga = [
  new SolicitudesCarga(0, "CARGA GENERAL", "Medias", "Hong Kong", 4, "1", "b", "PENDIENTE", "2022-12-30"),
  new SolicitudesCarga(1, "CARGA PELIGROSA", "Explosivos", "Umm Qasr", 300, "1", "b", "PENDIENTE", "2022-11-12"),
  new SolicitudesCarga(2, "CARGA GENERAL", "Bolsos y zapatos", "Cagliari", 40, "1", "b" ,"PENDIENTE", "2023-01-4")
];
```

Comment: Buenos días, qué haz intentado?

Comment: *Mi profesor pidió que usaramos `sort()`*... Ya leíste la documentación de [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?